# Swing spinner.getValue. Incompatible types?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

Today I've got one question about the spinner component in Swing.
When I want to get value of the spinner I just call the `getValue()` method on it, which returns an Object:

```
spinner.getValue();
```

After some coding I realized that I can't attribute `spinner.getValue()` to a variable of type String:

```
String value;
value = spinner.getValue(); // Incompatible types
```

But when I add a string before calling `getValue`, it works. Example:

```
String value;
value = "Spinner value: " + spinner.getValue();
```

Someone could explain this behavior?

Comment: In the future when asking about such errors or exceptions, always post the complete unedited error or exception method.

Answer (score 4):

```
spinner.getValue();
```

returns an `Object`. In order to assign it to a `String` variable, you need to convert it *(downcast)*. & that's what happens when you add an `Object` to a `String` : it gets evaluated to a `String`.

```
String value;

// Implicit call to 'spinner.getValue().toString()' , 
// then concatenation, then assignment
value = "Spinner value: " + spinner.getValue();
```

Comment: I keep trying to edit your answer and end up conflicting with your own edits, so: "add a `String` to an `Object`" is semantically backwards; it should be "add an `Object` to a `String`".  Also, you should point out that "evaluated to a `String`" is actually done by Java automatically calling `toString()` on the `Object` reference.